# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't see partitions

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

My laptop has 3 partitions, but when I install Ubuntu none of them are visible as in [this screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/4ru4drfkb/) from the partition editor on the Live Media.

If I create a partition and shrink my volume C partition, I can see the new Ubuntu partition shrink.

But if there are 3 partitions on my laptop they are not visible during installation.  Please help.

Comment: To help answer more specifically, please let us know the history or that laptop such as, whether it is brand new laptop and were you using with another OS(Windows) or Ubuntu operating system earlier and was there any data before etc, then it may help us to suggest you backup your data(using recovery softwares) using live CD before you proceed.

Answer (score 1):

As this [image](http://postimg.org/image/4ru4drfkb/) shows, you have 500 GB hard disk and may be there was 3 partitions earlier. But accidentally you may have deleted them and all 500 GB appears as free space(merged). That means its unallocated space and can be used for creating new partitions.

Comment: not. I did not delete it. 

This partition of my notebook. but why in ubuntu can not read it. 


[images] [1] 


   [1]: http://s29.postimg.org/muubh3wcl/03112014462.jpg

Comment: Rerer http://askubuntu.com/questions/452335/unable-to-recognize-and-create-partitions-for-ubuntu-installation-on-dell-inspir