# UEFI Installation -- Unable to Find HDD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I am attempting to install Ubuntu on a HP Envy 15, my intention is to have this dual-bootable with the standard Windows 10 installation.

So far, I have made the following progress:

- Created a live-USB drive to boot from
- Disabled "Secure Boot" in the BIOS (to make USB boot available)
- Booted onto the live-USB and run the installer

However, the installer does not "recognize" the internal HDD in the laptop.

I have run `gparted`, `parted -l`, `fdisk -l` and `lshw -class disk` all list the live-USB drive as `/dev/sda`, but the internal HDD is not present in the output from *any* of those commands.

---

As a diagnostic, I have tried enabling "legacy mode" in BIOS, and booting from the live-USB. It is clear form the loading screen that the live-USB is booting from BIOS (and not UEFI).

Running `fdisk -l` shows that the internal HDD has been successfully mounted as `/dev/sdb`.

Why is the disk presented in BIOS mode but not UEFI?

---

Given my intentions are to dual-boot with Windows 10, I understand that it is necessary to install Ubuntu whilst booted in UEFI mode?

Comment: can you please copy the `lsblk` output here ?

Comment: Can you provide the brand//model number of the hard disk itself? (suspecting EFI driver only signed for use with Windows)

Comment: @muhajirframe - lsblk shows sda/sda1/loop0, no reference to other disks.

Comment: @Fabby the disk is a Samsung ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD

Comment: Was the issue resolved?

Comment: @Charlie Afraid not. After failing to get this working the laptop went back to the store.

Comment: @jwa - sorry to hear that. Your problem perfectly describes the problem that I am having with a Dell XPS 15. Dell Tech support have just told me that this is unresolvable, so my laptop is going back to the store as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Ubuntu installer not detect the hard drive during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99038/why-does-the-ubuntu-installer-not-detect-the-hard-drive-during-installation)