# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS unrecognized hard drive -- not enough disk space to install

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, 16.04

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a partitioned windows 10 laptop (Dell XPS 13 9350, 250 GB SSD, intel i5-6200u @ 2.30GHz CPU, 8 GB of ram). I've livebooted it without issue from a USB, but am met with the error that "You need at least 8.4 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 8.0".

Typing `sudo fdisk -l` yields this:

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.3 GiB, 1433468928 bytes, 2799744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       32 15633407 15633376  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I can't see the hard drive listed there, and consequently there's no disk space to install the OS to. Unsure of what to do to resolve this.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lshw -C storage -C disk`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Had the same problem with almost the exact same hardware. The issue was with the [SATA mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99038/why-the-ubuntu-installer-does-not-detect-the-hard-drive-during-installation). It needs to be changed to *AHCI* mode in the BIOS settings. This can be done with the instructions found [here](http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15006-attn-ssd-owners-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-10-installation.html), printed below for completeness.

> 1. Run Command Prompt as Admin
> 2. Invoke a Safe Mode boot with the command: bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
> 3. Restart the PC and enter your BIOS during bootup.
> 4. Change from IDE to AHCI mode then Save & Exit.
> 5. Windows 10 will launch in Safe Mode.
> 6. Right click the Window icon and select to run the Command Prompt in Admin mode from among the various options.
> 7. Cancel Safe Mode booting with the command: bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
> 8. Restart your PC once more and this time it will boot up normally but with AHCI mode activated.
> 9. Bask in the reflected glory of being a total Windows 10 God

You can then boot in to Ubuntu from the USB, and the installer should recognise the hard drive.

Comment: having the same issue on a Ideapad 710s, there is no option to change the AHCI mode however

Comment: Sorry, this was only tested on an identical machine to the OP

Comment: wondering if changing this will effect the windows partition/boot?

Comment: @AlexanderMills If done correctly this procedure should have no effect on the Windows partition, but take care

Comment: Solved my issues on dell xps 15 9560, thanks! Anyway (at least in my case) there is no need to use windows prompt nor booting in safe mode... I just edited the SATA in the bios before booting ;)

Comment: This did the job for me to allow windows boot in AHCI mode. Though I had to disable safe mode in the BIOS in order successfully install Ubuntu alongside windows 10 (I could not boot from the USB at all when the safe boot was enabled)