# Ubuntu tries to install onto USB (which contains ISO files) instead of computer drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, 16.04

I'm trying to dual boot my Dell xps 15 with 512 gb ssd drive. I've created a boot device with a USB (Ubuntu 16.04). However, after selecting language in the installation process it says I need at least 8.5 gb disk space and that my computer only has 8.0 GB (which is the size of my USB stick I'm installing Ubuntu from). Running gparted in a live session also only shows my USB's storage, not my actual drive. Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: The problem is due to the hard disk is not recognized by the live installer. When i researched more onto that topic, i found the real cause. Apparently, the problem resides on the SATA disk side. Had the same problem and this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/764353/ubuntu-16-04-lts-unrecognized-hard-drive-not-enough-disk-space-to-install) helped me to move forward. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the screen titled "Installation type" there is an option to select where you would like to install Ubuntu. It is listed as "Something else".  Click on that and continue.  You should then be shown the existing partition table of your computer. From there, you can select where to install Ubuntu, you can create a new partition for it if needed, and you can select where the boot loader will be installed. Select your drive and the partition you would like to install it on and click install now. You can usually leave the boot loader installation device alone when you are dual booting, but it could get more complicated in the future.

Comment: Where are you supposed to get this screen?