# Why am I getting the error "You need at least 8.5 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 0.0B"?

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.0.4 onto a separate harddrive on my computer. I created a bootable USB using the LinuxLive USB Creator 2.9.4.

I plugged it in, booted it up, and then tried to install it. I got as far as the screen with "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu." When I click "Install Ubuntu," It gives me the error "You need at least 8.5 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 0.0B." It doesn't give me the option to select any of my three drives, and goes straight to this error when I select it.

I am using a USB 2.0 at 8 GB. I'm trying to install it to a SAMSUNG HD642JJ ATA Harddrive with 640 GB of space. I recently formatted it, and it is completely empty of anything.

My other two drives--my Storage and Windows drives--are a ST31000524AS ATA Device and a WDC WD1600HLFS-60G6U2 ATA Device (Which I'm pretty sure is a WD Velociraptor).

When I click "Try Ubuntu," Ubuntu boots up just fine, and all three drives are detected by the operating system.

All of the ports are set to IDE.

**Attempted Fixes:**

I unplugged my Windows and Storage drives and left only the Bootable USB and the SAMSUNG drive that I was trying to install to plugged in. This did not solve the issue.

I also saw that there was sometimes an issue with the ports being set to IDE while running the installer, so I tried setting my ports first to AHCI and then RAID and attempted the installation, with no luck. This was the only solution that I could find online, so I have no clue what to do.

**System:**

AMD FX-6300 Six-Core processor 3.5 Ghz

16 GB RAM

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760

ASUS M5A78L-USB3 Motherboard

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo parted -l` ?

Comment: "parted: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_65-linux-gnu/libdevmaper.so.1.02.1: cannot read file data: Input/output error"

Comment: This is likely due to improper formatting. Make sure you have your hard drive formatted into the correct type.

Comment: Why are you trying to change your ports to IDE when your drive(s) are SATA and USB? Are you running in VirtualBox? Please give more detail. Cheers, Al

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS unrecognized hard drive -- not enough disk space to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764353/ubuntu-16-04-lts-unrecognized-hard-drive-not-enough-disk-space-to-install)

Comment: It might be a problem with the installer not the disk

Answer (score 0):

I also have same issue while making duel boot. there is one option that you can make install is to change your SATA configuration mode

my laptop default is *SATA config* -> *intel*
but that one not compatible with installing Ubuntu.

So I changed to AHCI mode, so I can install Ubuntu it will detect your disk.
But only the drawback for this method is that everytime you need to switch back to intel mode if you want to use Windows.

To change the mode : go to *Boot* -> *SATA configuration* -> *AHCI/Intel*

note: disable *secure boot* and *fast boot*