# Ubuntu 18.10 installer cannot detect HP x360 15 SSD (Intel CPU)

Tags: ssd

As the title states, I am unable to install Ubuntu on my HP ENVY x360 - 15m-cn0011dx. The laptop has a M.2 NVME SSD, and the installer cannot locate it, gparted in a live environment cannot locate it, and I'm stumped.

I've tried all of the options in HPs bios.

I've disabled fastboot.

I confirmed there is no raid or optane running.

Other than wiping the SSD on another computer and trying it that way, I'm out of ideas.

Ideally, I'd dual boot with Windows, but any help is appreciated.

Edit:
This is the laptop in question [Best Buy Link](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-envy-x360-2-in-1-15-6-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i5-8gb-memory-256gb-solid-state-drive-hp-finish-in-natural-silver/6237354.p?skuId=6237354&ref=212&loc=1&&ref=212&loc=1&ds_rl=1266837&gclid=Cj0KCQiAm5viBRD4ARIsADGUT25FQnWs55My2EoH2QAXg73uqUylToM-XA3ptN5Z387S6JpoaXd0TQ4aAkGJEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Edit 2 ) I have concluded that due to HP not allowing me to change the storage to AHCI, without replacing the SSD, a secondary OS (or installer) is unable to even detect the drive.

Comment: Was the nvme SSD factory installed or installed by you?

Comment: @Tek The SSD is factory installed

Comment: Did you make sure the nvme drive setting isn't RAID but AHCI in the bios?

Comment: @Tek the lovely HP bios doesn't have an option to change raid settings. I can see the Intel RST setting and it says something to the effect of "not raid."  I did see somewhere else about changing to AHCI in command prompt in Windows that I haven't tried yet

Comment: @Tek https://askubuntu.com/a/776014/916633 is the post I referenced

Comment: Pretty sure Ubuntu can't read nvme drives that are in RAID mode in BIOS. If you can't change that it might be a BIOS limitation and you may be out of luck. I got the HP Envy x360 AMD Ryzen and removed the HDD and put in an NVME drive and was able to install Ubuntu. I think those instrunctions you linked are your last resort for making it work on an Intel system. Let us know if that solves it!

Comment: @Tek no dice. I'm out of ideas. Settling for win10 for now

Comment: Yep might just be a bios limitation. Have you tried updating your BIOS to see if you get the drive mode option on another BIOS version?

Comment: @Tek the bios was on the latest revision from HP. Without replacing the SSD, I think I'm out of luck.

Comment: So... return it and get an HP x360 AMD Ryzen processor one? :D