# boot - not enoug disk space to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside windows 10 on laptop (Acer Swift SF315-S2).

I first allocated some 300Gb to install Windows, as shown below:

[image: b]

When I then boot from the USB stick with ubuntu, I am prompted to the installation, but then I get the following message at some point:

[image]

I have found a possible answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764353/ubuntu-16-04-lts-unrecognized-hard-drive-not-enough-disk-space-to-install) so I change the SATA mode on the bios from `RST with optane` to `AHCI`. Windows had then troubble booting, but then it managed to recover, so I set the SATA mode back to the default i.e. `RST with optane` and Windows is again bootable, though I cannot install Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is this somehow dependent on the computer model? I saw that changing the SATA mode works for some, but not for others.

Comment: In "Install Ubuntu" select "Something else" select the unallocated space next to the Windows partition and click the + lower left. Specify the amount of space you want (out of 293GB), Use as ext4, check Format and /. Make sure Bootloader goes on sda.

Comment: Where would I select "something else"? In the live version (e.g. by right clicking it?)? Note that the error that I got in the screenshot above was just after selecting the language, keyboard layout and Wi-Fi, which means that I was not prompted to the screen where I could select/ create the partitions.

Comment: First screen is Welcome, (Language), choose Install. Second screen is Keyboard. Third is Wireless. Fourth is Updates and Fifth is Installation type, Something else is option at bottom of list.

Comment: Oops, it looks like it is trying to install to the flash drive, check if The installer is seeing the HDD. Try Ubuntu and open Disks. Check if HDD is showing. If so go to Install Ubuntu icon and see if you can install from there. You can also try installing after booting to RAM. Press shift after starting boot, press esc at language, press F6, press escape again, then type <space>toram and enter. Do you have Fast Boot and Secure Boot turned off?

Comment: In fact Ubuntu is not recognising the HDD. If I go to disks it shows only the usb stick and another 2.0GB loop device (/cdrom...). I will then try to install after booting to RAM, shall I disable Fast Boot and Secure Boot for that?

Comment: Yes, I understand that Fast Boot and Secure Boot should always be disabled when booting Ubuntu.