# Installing Ubuntu on compute stick, can't find hard drive

Tags: boot, computestick

I have a compute stick. It **did not** come with Windows but I installed Windows. It worked, but I couldn't ever find the product key.

Now I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 using a flash drive.  However, the installer can't see the hard drive. Using Sudo fdisk -l only reveals the USB drive I'm installing with. If I type it in without the USB drive, it shows nothing.

I did see this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99038/why-the-ubuntu-installer-does-not-detect-the-hard-drive-during-installation). However, some of the advice didn't seem applicable. It is a compute stick, so none of the pointers about changing what port the hard drive plugs into work for me.

I'm an Ubuntu rookie, so any input would be helpful. I was under the impression that I could put Ubuntu on a compute stick as long as it had not come with Windows. I do not want to dual boot.

Comment: Since 12.04 is now EOL, I'd recommend you start over with 14.04LTS or, if the compute stick has the hardware for it, 16.04LTS.

Comment: Use 16.04 LTS or newer.

Comment: **Use 16.04**. The older versions don't have support for the newer hardware like NVME

Comment: Dang. No way around it? I'm using the compute stick for a Xibo 1.6 digital signage display. Their website said they stopped supporting Ubuntu at 12.04.

Comment: No, no way around it. And again, even if it worked, 12.04 is unsupported.