# Ubuntu 18.04 installation is stuck on the Installation type screen

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I am using a Lenovo Yoga. I am using a USB containing Ubuntu 18.04, and the Try Ubuntu desktop consistently works.

However, the installer always freezes on the *Installation type* screen. The page loads with an empty partition table and "new partition table" is disabled.

If I click "Install Now", I am left with the error message that a root has not been set.
If I click **+**, the program freezes and the computer must be restarted.
**-** shows the same message as install now, but I am allowed to proceed with the installation but with many warning messages.
The installation inevitably fails.
Any other button also leads to the freeze or failure.
Do I need to do something to my BIOS or is the download I have broken?

[image]

Comment: The answer from here worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/99038/why-does-the-ubuntu-installer-not-detect-the-hard-drive-during-installation

Answer (score 1):

drive not 'seen' -> disable RAID HD in the bios