# Internal Hard Drive not detected while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, hard-drive, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron 3420 laptop.  The problem is my 500GB hard drive is not detected during installation.  I also tried `gparted` and the Disks application, but the hard drive is not detected in either of them.  An input output error is shown.

I've checked similar questions but none of them have helped.

Feel free to ask, if further information is needed.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: check bios settings, if HD have raid feature on, disable it

Comment: @cmak.fr How to do this thing ?

Comment: Please add the following to your question: What you mean by "not detected"? (Is it not visible to `gparted`?  Or just unusable by the installer?) The specific error messages you see. The "similar questions" you checked. Drive and partition information reported by `gparted` (if available).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Ubuntu installer not detect the hard drive during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99038/why-does-the-ubuntu-installer-not-detect-the-hard-drive-during-installation)