# No Partition to Select - Ubuntu 18.04.3 Fresh Install

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, boot-partition

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 on an old HP Desktop. I already reformatted the hard drive (tried both unallocated and EXT3) and yet haven't been able to select the partition during install. Any and all help is appreciated.

[Device specifications](https://support.hp.com/bg-en/document/c03154290)

[image: Fresh Install - Partition Selection Screenshot]

**EDIT:** Adding screenshots for gparted and failed installation error message.

[image: gparted Screenshot]

[Fresh Install Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTV21.png)

[image: EXT4 gparted Screenshot]

Comment: Run `gparted` and post the screenshot.

Comment: Updated with screenshots

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the picture directly - I'm too new to do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/dev/sda1` partition and create a new `ext4` partition.

It is unclear why you selected `ext3`. Most likely Ubuntu can't be installed on `ext3` now because it is obsolete.

Comment: I'll try that again, but I've now tried EXT 2/3/4...

Comment: Also check what is the partition table format. If you are using BIOS, then it should be MBR, not GPT.

Comment: Try to install now.

Comment: Make sure you press `Apply` before you exit `gparted`.

Comment: Did both, no change, same result.

Comment: You did "new partition table"? And what if you press `+` in the installation window?

Comment: New partition table is greyed out (shown in screenshot) and the + crashes the installer... very odd

Comment: Really odd. Let's wait for someone else. I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: Did you click on the change button first?  Will also need to choose / for partition.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a dual boot on a newer Dell recently, and I had to change the SATA from IDE to AHCI (or the other way around) in the BIOS before the partitions would show up on the installation screen. Might be the case here.

[Why does the Ubuntu installer not detect the hard drive during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99038/why-does-the-ubuntu-installer-not-detect-the-hard-drive-during-installation)

Comment: Hey David! I actually tried doing this earlier with no luck sadly :/